# Why a member function cannot modify the local copy of the variable from the main function?

Tags: c++, member-functions

I'm trying to understand how a member function of a class behaves when creating a local copy of the 
private variable. (Not when accessing it through reference)

So I have this code and my understanding is this:

1. Inside the member function get_name0() the vector "name" is a local copy of the private data member "name".
2. Adding the element "f0" inside the get_name0() function should make the object np0 to have {ab, f0} and it does. No problem here.
3. Adding the element "m0" in the main function should make(?) the object np0 to have {ab, f0, m0} but instead it has {ab, f0, f0}. I don't understand why this happens and probably I'm wrong somewhere?

Thanks in advance to anyone who clarifies this for me!

```
class Name_pairs
{
public:
    vector<string> get_name0() // this is a member function that returns a copy; name is a local copy
    {
        name.push_back("f0"); // the copy can be changed by the member function
        return name;          
    }

private:
    vector<string> name = {"ab"};
};

int main()
{
    Name_pairs np0;
    np0.get_name0().push_back("m0"); // this should change the local copy not the "name" object but it doesn't
    cout << "\nnp0 object: ";
    for (string s : np0.get_name0())   // this should print the local copy from the inside of get_name0() function
        cout << s << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_name()` returns a copy of the member. Two different calls return two different copies of the member.

This will result in the expected output:

```
int main()
{
    Name_pairs np0;
    auto name = np0.get_name0();
    name.push_back("m0");
    cout << "\nnp0 object: ";
    for (string s : name)
        cout << s << " ";
}
```

In your code there is no "local copy". The vector returned is a temporary that ceases to exist at the end of the statement.

> 1. Inside the member function get_name0() the vector "name" is a local copy of the private data member "name".

No. Inside the member function `name` is the member called `name`. What you return from the method is a copy.

> 2. Adding the element "f0" inside the get_name0() function should make the object np0 to have {ab, f0} and it does. No problem here.

No problem here, but you are adding to the member, not to some "local copy". You add first then copy (and return the copy from the method).

> 3. Adding the element "m0" in the main function should make(?) the object np0 to have {ab, f0, m0} but instead it has {ab, f0, f0}.

The object you add `"m0"` to is gone after this line:

```
np0.get_name0().push_back("m0");
```

Its lifetime ended. You have to way to see it ever again. The next call to `get_name0()` will give you a new copy of the member, after adding again `"f0"` to the member.

Comment: Thanks idclev! now I understand my error... instead of printing the new "name" I was printing another call to np0.get_name0(), which is a new copy, like you said... and many thanks for correcting my understanding of what it means to return a copy!

Answer (score 3):

Every call to `get_name0` will add the value `f0` to the `name` vector. Since you have 2 calls to this function, you get 2 copies of `f0` inserted. Note that the usage in the range-for loop is also a call to this function.

However, the vector returned by `get_name0` is a *copy* of the `name` vector, so adding an element to that copy will not change the member variable. If you want to actually change the member, you need to return the vector by reference, like this:

```
vector<string>& get_name0() {
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `get_name0` returns by value, not by reference, so in your case your

```
np0.get_name0().push_back("m0");
```

behaves like

```
{
    vector<string> temporary = np0.get_name0();
    temporary.push_back("m0");
}   //  here temporary is destroyed
```

Your `push_back("m0");` only modifies the temporary, not the `vector` stored in `np0`. If you want to modify the `vector` ind `np0` then `get_name0` should return by reference.

```
vector<string>& get_name0();
```

Take care that with `get_name0` you are giving clients of your class full access to the data member. If you only want clients to read data, then make the returned `vector` `const`

```
const vector<string>& get_name0();
```

Or remove the function at all and provide only the member modification functions that you need (like `add_name` for example).